# How can I tell if a comment flag was deemed helpful because a moderator saw it and handled it?

Tags: support, flags

I just flagged a comment in a comment chain that was degenerating. The flag was to inform a moderator that the corresponding user was planning to delete their posts because they were mad (more or less).

That whole discussion in comments was pretty bad and likely had been flagged by many users and therefore got deleted.

The flag was marked as helpful on my profile.

How can I be sure that the *helpful* mark means the moderator actually saw it and will take action, rather than the comment was simply deleted?

Comment: I know custom mod flags on post are *never* automatically resolved (one way or another).  I'm pretty sure the same is true of custom comment flags.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to know that. The only indication we get is if the flag is helpful or not.

Comment: In this case, yes, I did see your flag, and yes, this has been addressed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way for a user to tell if their comment flag was handled automatically (either by the community user, or by accumulated flags), or manually by a moderator.

Only a moderator has access to this information, and the only way for a moderator to relay this information to a user is if they ask, in some other way. Moderators cannot reply to comment flags in the same way that they can with post flags, for example.

Comment: By all means, do what you need to do in respect to the flag. I would just like to know that the flag wasn't ignored/missed because of the batch delete.

Comment: I read the question as asking if a moderator ever looked at that flag and made a concious choice as to what action should be taken, as opposed to the flag being automatically marked as handled because of some action taken by someone not currently reviewing the flag.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: Yeah and I'm telling you there's no way for you to know this unless a moderator tells you.

Comment: Cool, then @corresponding-moderator, please tell me, so I don't have to go reflag that post.

Comment: @BoltClock So deleting a comment clears all custom moderator flags on that comment?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: I wasn't the one who handled your flag, but yes, the situation has been taken care of.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - One thing I would suggest is that if what you're flagging for is important for us to see, use a custom flag on the main post instead of a comment. That guarantees that a moderator will see it at some point, and we can provide an appropriate custom response as BoltClock points out. You can point to the comment in the flag, and we'll see it even if it's deleted. People often do this for situations like the one you encountered.

Comment: @Servy: I'd assume so. I've personally never seen pending flags on deleted comments, and there are actually some limitations to the comment flag handling mechanism that make it completely impossible for a pending flag to be handled on certain types of deleted comment. (I'm deliberately being vague here...)

Comment: @BradLarson (or BoltClock) please consider [edit]  "use a custom flag on the main post instead of a comment" into main answer as question seem to be generic enough and this is useful piece of advice hidden in comments (I'd do it myself, but may miss amount of "being vague" necessary for this type of recommendation :) )